# From which domain name the post request comes from?

Tags: php, curl, server, http-post, domain-name

I've built an API for providing some data a user needs to get. So every time a user hits the server with a curl post request and the server checks the header auth token and provides the data. Now I want to

> **check the domain from where the post request comes from**

. How could I check this?

Answer (score 0):

That isn't feasible as far as I can tell.

- Browsers may send a [Referer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer) (sic) HTTP header, but Curl clients don't normally care. In any case the information is provided by the client so it isn't something you can trust.
- The IP address of the incoming request may or may not be the actual client address. Even if it is, an IP address can resolve to zero, one or several domains.